# python elementTree, appending new element to a parsed xml file has no effect, no error

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I've read through as many related posts as i could find but none of them have helped.  I have a simple xml file, I need to add a new element (look_1) as a child of another element (Looks). 
I can't seem to get the xml formatting to work here so the tree looks something like this:

```
AssetRoot
    info_Materials
        Looks/
    /info_Materials
/AssetRoot
```

The goal is to produce this:

```
AssetRoot
    info_Materials
        Looks
            look_1
                (additional elements from a future script)
            /look_1
        /Looks
    /info_Materials
/AssetRoot
```

I have the following script which doesnt throw any errors, but also doesn't seem to do anything to the file.

```
   def editXML(filename):

        print 'editing xml file...'
        tree = xml.parse(filename)
        root = tree.getroot()

        looks = root.findall('.//Looks')
        print looks

        look_1 = xml.Element('Look_1')
        look_1.text = 'foobar'
        looks.append(look_1)


         with open(filename, 'w') as fn:
         print 'writing xml file...'
         tree.write(fn)
         print 'file write successful'


    if __name__ == '__main__':

    editXML(assetInfo)
```

I can confirm that *looks = root.findall('.//Looks')* finds the correct element if i print 'looks'.  If I understand correctly, the result of element.findall() doesn't point to the element but the value of the element? So how do I get the actual element so can manipulate it? If I append 'look_1' to 'root' rather than 'look' it works,  so my question is how do I append a new element to a nested child element

From my reading I understand that lxml would make this very simple but I'd rather not have to include additional dependencies.

EDIT: I did some rewriting and found the following to work:

```
def editXML(filename):

    print 'editing xml file...'
    tree = xml.ElementTree(file=filename)
    root = tree.getroot()
    looks = root[2][1]

    look_1 = xml.Element('Look_1')
    look_1.text = 'foobar'
    looks.append(look_1)

    with open(filename, 'w') as fn:
        print 'writing xml file...'
        tree.write(fn)
        print 'file write successful'


if __name__ == '__main__':

    editXML(assetInfo)
```

Its perhaps not the most elegant solution but it should work for my purposes, if anyone has a better solution I'd be interested to know. Thanks.

Comment: The doc for `findall` says that it returns a list....do you need to do something like `looks[0].append(look_1)`?

Answer (score 0):

To close the thread, I'll mark it as answered, As stated in my edit, this was the solution I came up with.

```
def editXML(filename):

    print 'editing xml file...'
    tree = xml.ElementTree(file=filename)
    root = tree.getroot()
    looks = root[2][1]

    look_1 = xml.Element('Look_1')
    look_1.text = 'foobar'
    looks.append(look_1)

    with open(filename, 'w') as fn:
        print 'writing xml file...'
        tree.write(fn)
        print 'file write successful'


if __name__ == '__main__':

    editXML(assetInfo)
```